# I have a belongs to relationship in laravel 8 and it returns null when I am trying to use that relationship in the tinker shell

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-relations, laravel-models

I am using Laravel 8 and I have the following very simple models and migrations,

**Author Model**

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Author extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
 
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile');
    }
}
```

**Profile Model**

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
 
    public function author()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
    }
}
```

**create_authors_table migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAuthorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('authors');
    }
}
```

**create_profiles_table migration**

```
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 
class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
 
            $table->unsignedInteger('author_id')->unique();
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
        });
    }
 
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

***Despite having the above models and migrations, if I create a new `Profile` model in tinker shell and do `$profile->author()` it returns `null`. I can not understand from where the problem is coming from.***

(I tried changing `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');` to `$this->belongsTo(Author::class);` and `$this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile');` to `$this->hasOne(Profile::class);` and restarting the tinker. The issue still persists. I even tried changing all the unsigned integer keys to unsigned big integers and the issue still persists.)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the problem. The solution is simple, I have forgotten to add the all important `return` statement inside the `author()` method inside the `Profile` model.

It should be,
`return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');` instead of `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');`

Answer (score 0):

try with this one
**return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id', 'id');**
instead of
**$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');**